# SSH Authentication with github from Jenkins Shared-library

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, dsl

I am trying to pull github code from Jenkins Shared Library with SSH Username and private authentication but getting below error.

ERROR: Credentials 'SSH_jenkins_with_Github' is of type 'SSH Username with private key' where 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.StringCredentials' was expected

Anyone can help here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a Credential Type mismatch; There are multiple types [available](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/) (not counting plugins). You are using a more "complex" `SSH Username with private key` linked to the id: `SSH_jenkins_with_Github`, where a more "simple" `Secret text` (String) Credentials Type is needed. More info / examples are found [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials)